# How to join a dimension table onto a key table with a variable number of dimensions?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains dimension/index information for a look-up table, looking like this:

| Lookup Table | Dimension | Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Products | 1 | 0 | Furniture |
| Products | 1 | 1 | Electronics |
| Products | 1 | 2 | Accessories |
| Products | 2 | 0 | New |
| Products | 2 | 1 | Used |
| Products | 2 | 2 | Refurbished |
| Products | 3 | 0 | P000 |
| Products | 3 | 1 | P001 |
| Products | 3 | 2 | P002 |
| Products | 3 | 3 | P003 |

And a cell values table looking like this:

| Lookup Table | Dimension1Key | Dimension2Key | Dimension3Key | ... | Dimension15Key | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Products | 0 | 1 | 3 | ... | NULL | 100.00 |

*This record would be Furniture, Used, P003: Value 100.00*

And I want to join these two tables in a way that gives me a human-readable output like the below, but would work for other lookup tables besides "Products", and these tables may have any amount of dimensions from 1-15.

| Dimension1 | Dimension2 | Dimension3 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Furniture | Used | P003 | 100.00 |

I can easily code a SQL query that uses a Common Table Expression for the first table and then a JOIN for each dimension that I need, but this is really clumsy and would require me to put in between 1 and 15 joins and would break if I changed from the current 3-dimensional lookup table to say a different 5D one. Is there an elegant solution for this problem?

I've tried all kinds of cross-joins, recursive etc but nothing seems to make sense to me.
This is what I have at the moment, but it will only work for this specific number of dimensions:

```sql
WITH Dim As (
   SELECT Dimension, Key, Value
   FROM dimension_table
)

SELECT d1.Value, d2.Value, d3.Value, c.Value
FROM   cells_table c
JOIN   Dim d1
ON     d1.Key = c.Dimension1Key
AND    d1.Dimension = 1
JOIN   Dim d2
ON     d2.Key = c.Dimension2Key
AND    d2.Dimension = 2
JOIN   Dim d3
ON     d3.Key = c.Dimension3Key
AND    d3.Dimension = 3
```

Comment: This is just a downside of an EAV model. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios In fact this is a little worse because it's a "pivoted" EAV model with multiple named columns. . I don't really have any advice but to do some reading on EAV and see if anyone else has come up with something more elegant.

Comment: Do you have any say in this data model, or are you just working with what you're given?